# Failed to convert from JSON;Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values at (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

```
   @KafkaListener(id = ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, topics = ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT)
    @SendTo
    public Product GetProduct(String id) {
        return _productRepository.findByid(id);
    }
```

## Kafka Configuration

```
    @Configuration
        public class KafkaConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class));
    }


            @Bean
            public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> replyer(ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf,
                                                                                     ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> containerFactory) {
        
                containerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate(pf));
                ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> container = replyContainer(containerFactory);
                ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, Object> replyer = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
                return replyer;
            }
        
            @Bean
            public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> replyContainer(
                    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> containerFactory) {
        
                ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> container =
                        containerFactory.createContainer(ProductTopicConstants.LISTNER_CONTAINER);
                container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(ProductTopicConstants.LISTNER_CONTAINER);
                containerFactory.setMessageConverter(new JsonMessageConverter());
                container.setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchLoggingErrorHandler());
                return container;
            }
        
            @Bean
            public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf) {
                return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
            }
        }
```

## Kafka Producer

```
   @Override
    public ProductViewModel GetProduct(String id) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> future =
                this._replyTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<>(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, 0, null,id));
        LOG.info(future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata().toString());
        var products = (Product)future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value();
        var mappedProducts = mapper.convertValue(products, new TypeReference<Product>() { });
        return new ProductViewModel(mappedProducts.getId(), mappedProducts.getName(), mappedProducts.getPrice(), mappedProducts.getDescription());
    }
```

## Kafka Configuration

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  kafka:
    bootstrapAddress: localhost:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: '*'
```

## Topic

```
@Bean
    public static NewTopic GetProduct() {
        return new NewTopic(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic GetProducts() {
        return TopicBuilder.name(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS).partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }
    @Bean
    public NewTopic GetProductsContainer() {
        return TopicBuilder.name(ProductTopicConstants.LISTNER_CONTAINER).partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }
```

## Error

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1887) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1792) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1719) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1617) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1064) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1902) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:117) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:123) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:309) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1854) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1836) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1779) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:632) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:679) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1703) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parsePosNumber(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1346) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4620) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4469) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:114) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

2020-07-26 21:52:47.026  INFO 3997 --- [etProduct-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-GetProduct-4, groupId=GetProduct] Seeking to offset 25 for partition GetProduct-0
2020-07-26 21:52:47.029 ERROR 3997 --- [etProduct-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1887) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1792) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1719) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1617) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1064) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1902) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:117) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:123) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:309) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1854) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1836) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1779) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:632) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:679) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1703) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parsePosNumber(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1346) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4620) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4469) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:114) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

2020-07-26 21:52:47.534  INFO 3997 --- [etProduct-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-GetProduct-4, groupId=GetProduct] Seeking to offset 25 for partition GetProduct-0
2020-07-26 21:52:47.537 ERROR 3997 --- [etProduct-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1887) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1792) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1719) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1617) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1064) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1902) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:117) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:123) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:309) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1854) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1836) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1779) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:632) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:679) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1703) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parsePosNumber(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1346) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773) ~[jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4620) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4469) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:114) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

2020-07-26 21:52:48.049  INFO 3997 --- [etProduct-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-GetProduct-4, groupId=GetProduct] Seeking to offset 25 for partition GetProduct-0
2020-07-26 21:52:48.052 ERROR 3997 --- [etProduct-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Error handler threw an exception
```

## Output in Consumer console

[image]

All the combination I have tried but none of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the consumer side configuration; you are doing double JSON conversion `JsonMessageConverter` is being applied, which is unnecessary since you have already converted the JSON to a String in the `JsonDeserializer`. You either need to replace the deserializer with a simple `StringDeserializer` or `ByteArrayDeserializer` so the converter has something to convert.

**EDIT**

So, the problem is that your `ProductListener` has a bean

```java
@Bean
public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
    return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
}
```

and Boot is auto-configuring it into the listener container factory and you have a `JsonDeserializer` so, as I said, you are doing double deserialization. I was able to reproduce it by adding that message converter bean into your stripped down app.

You can either use a different factory for that listener, or override the deserializer on the listener itself...

```java
@KafkaListener(id = ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, topics = ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT,
        clientIdPrefix = "getProd", 
        properties = ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG
            + "=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
```

Comment: I replace the consumer key-deserializer & value-deserializer to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer but no luck same issue

Comment: That doesn't make sense; where are you configuring the `JsonMessageConverter`?

Comment: I don't know how to configure, can you please show me. I have just used containerFactory.setMessageConverter(new JsonMessageConverter());

Comment: But your configuration above doesn't show that; we can't help you if you only provide half of the picture. You need to provide a complete stripped-down version of your project somewhere so someone can take a look at what's wrong.

Comment: Just updated the code, forgot to edit the code before the comment.

Comment: You are still not showing the consumer side only the reply container. On the consumer side, you should NOT use a `JsonMessageConverter` in the container factory, just use a JsonDeserializer.

Comment: Now I have added

Comment: Your configuration is confusing - is the consumer in the same application as the replying template? Maybe it would be easier if you posted your whole projects someplace so I can see what you have done wrong.

Comment: Here is the repo - https://github.com/anandjaisy/kafkaResponse

Comment: That is too much code for me to navigate; you need to strip it down to something simple that only contains the Kafka bits and exhibits the behavior you observe - like I did in my answer to [your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058608/spring-boot-rest-api-with-spring-kafka).

Comment: Please can you help me, I have updated the repo with sorter code

Comment: Your project works fine for me: `$ curl localhost:8083/5f19a7e99933db43cb23e83d
{"id":null,"name":"Product A","price":23.0,"description":"Product A Description"}`

Comment: Have you tried since you stripped it down? Maybe you removed something that is affecting the configuration?

Comment: Yes; that was it - see the edit to my answer; works again now.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are so helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try changing JsonDeserializer to StringSerializer.

For some custom objects, you should config your consumer factory to understand its type:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, MyClass> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(MyClass.class));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean in the consumer:value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer. StringSerializer? But sometimes I need to send POJO object as well in the other method

Comment: For more detail, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132733/spring-kafka-multiple-listeners-for-different-objects-within-an-applicationcont

Comment: Do I need to create ReplyingKafkaTemplate, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer, ConsumerFactory for each consumer listener ??

Comment: You create each ConsumerFactory for each type you want. If it's just 1 type like String or a POJO, create 1 and use for all consumers